# ssh Client into boot2docker

Tags: docker

I an planning to use ExpanDrive(or any other ssh client) into boot2docker. I know of boot2docker ssh, but how do you use any client into boot2docker?

When using ssh keys I can see id_boot2docker and id_boot2docker.pub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Simply get the ip address using: `boot2docker ip`
- you can do `ssh docker@ip-address`.  password: tcuser
- In ExpandDrive , you should be able to specify this ip address with username: docker  password: tcuser

This method will work if you want to ssh using same machine. If you want to connect it remotely from any other machine,  you can setup port forwarding using virtualbox / vagrant and then use:

`ssh -p 2022 docker@host-ip-address`

where host-ip is the ip address of your mac (Assuming you are doing port forwarding to 2022 port).